# configure SFML for clion (windows)

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion

i am setting up a work environment for a school project on my windows computer. We are going to make a basic game using c++ and CLion. To make a game i need to use the SFML library. I have followed a few tutorials but i cant seem to get it to work anyway.

I have:

- Downloaded CLion and configured it with MinGW
- Downloaded SFML and copied its "findSFML.cmake" file to a new directory in my project that i call cmake_modules.
- Edited my CMakeLists.txt file so it looks like this:

> ```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
> project(testet)
>
> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
> set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
>
> add_executable(testet ${SOURCE_FILES})
> set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
> find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
> if (SFML_FOUND)
>     include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
>     target_link_libraries(testet ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
> endif()
> ```

These are the three steps that i see on every tutorial / answer. But I get the following error anyway:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\Benjamin\ClionProjects\testet
CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindSFML.cmake:355 (message):
Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY
SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY SFML_NETWORK_LIBRARY SFML_AUDIO_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
```

So it cant find the SFML? But should'nt the "findSFML.cmake" solve this? Any help is appretiated... Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing the `link_directories()` call. You can use it like this:

```
link_directories("C:/Path_To_Library")
```

This should help solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks the path is suppose to be the path to the SFML folder?

Comment: Yeah, I had to add this in my project that I was testing. I'm on linux, but it's the same concept: link_directories(/opt/dtSearchLinux/bin64)

Comment: hmmmm, i added link_directories("C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/SFML-2.4.1/bin") to my CMakesLists.txt but i still get the same error ...

Comment: Hm, okay. This question/answers might lead you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227010/cmake-finding-external-libraries

Comment: Thanks, that person had a similar problem and you tip was not that far of. I only had to add the path to my sfml library in the FindSFML.cmake file.

Comment: Ah, well I'm glad I was able to get you in the right direction. Those cmake files can be a pain :)

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully configured **SFML with CLion** on **Ubuntu 16.04** and I think it will be same for Window user also.

My project name is **SFML_TEST** so change every occurrence of **SFML_TEST with your project name.**

1. Create a new Clion C++ Project.
2. Navigate to /path/to/CLionProjects/[Project_Name]/CMakeLists.txt
3. After the following statement

   ```
   add_executable(SFML_TEST ${SOURCE_FILES})
   ```

   Add following lines of code

   ```
   set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
   find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
   if (SFML_FOUND)
   include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
   target_link_libraries(SFML_TEST ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
   endif()
   ```
4. Create a new directory /path/to/CLionProjects/[project_name]/cmake_modules/FindSFML.cmake
5. In FindSFML.cmake file paste the following line of code from the given file https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake
6. Done!!!.. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

my fix was, that I had to change the root path of SFML in the FindSFML.cmake

so just `set(SFML_ROOT Z://your_project)` after the block of comments and you are ready to go