# How to use SFML libraries with Clion on Windows10

Tags: c++, windows-10, sfml, clion

i'm trying to use SFML's library with CLion for a school project. I'm still not confident with programming and i am new to Clion.
After having download the library from SFML official site i read some tutorials, but i am a bit confused:
https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/

Infact in the Getting Started section there are two voice that concern me: "Compiling with Cmake" and "..Code::Blocks (MinGW).
Well i tryed both but with no results, then i landed here.
I saw a topic that helped a bit [configure SFML for clion (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773183/configure-sfml-for-clion-windows)
so i tried to follow the steps suggested.

The library is in C:\SFML-2.4.2

I copied FindSFML.cmake in SFMLProjects, located in C:\Users\Ludovico\ (the same path of the folder ClionProjects)
Then i gave it a try

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(provaSfml)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(provaSfml ${SOURCE_FILES})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/SFMLProjects")
link_directories(C:/SFML-2.4.2/bin)
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(provaSfml ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif ()
```

These are the error messages

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.3.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" - DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"     C:\Users\Ludovico\CLionProjects\provaSfml
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSFML.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SFML", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" with any of
  the following names:

     SFMLConfig.cmake
     sfml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SFML" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SFML_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SFML"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I'm thinking i did some mistakes even in the organization of folder...
can someone tell me some advice in order to clean the mess i have in my head?
What can i do to fix these problems?

Comment: I don't have any experience with SFML, but it looks like you can check the SFML_DIR environment variable and see if it points to the SFML executables directory. Have you tried this?

Comment: Have you checked that `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is actually the directory in which you put your `FindSFML.cmake` file?

Comment: no... i don't really know what path is CMAKE_MODULE_PATH (i hoped it was a default one)
i have the FindSFML.cmake here
C:\SFML-2.4.2\cmake\Modules