# Setting up Project with Clion and SFML works, but only the first time

Tags: c++, sfml, clion

So, i set up my Cloin/SFML project like this : [configure SFML for clion (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773183/configure-sfml-for-clion-windows)

and added the SFML_ROOT variable, and then it works exactly once, and every time i try too run it after the first, i get this error(gam is the project name, it is set correctly in the CMakeLists.txt file):

mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target 'gam'.  Stop.

How do i get it to work more than once?(It might be something as stupid as me clicking the wrong button to run this thing. I´m new to Clion and cmake)

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(gam)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(gam ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(gam ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

output of CMake when project is first initialized:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" D:\programierzeug\c++\test
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/programierzeug/c++/test/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

output of CMake when reloading project:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.2.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" D:\programierzeug\c++\test
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/programierzeug/c++/test/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

Comment: Can you provide your CMakeLists.txt maybe there's something setup wrong there.

Comment: CMAkeLists.txt:
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(gam)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(gam ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(gam ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()

Comment: Might be better if you edited your answer and added it there as code block, kind of hard to read in a comment.

Comment: just did that, never actually posted to stackoverflow before :'D

Comment: And what do you do when you get that error? How did you setup CLion? Also note that as of [SFML 2.5.0](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24070.0) you no longer have to use `include_directories`. And the linking order is wrong, it should be `graphics window network audio system`

Comment: Have you tried setting the `SFML_ROOT ` variable inside your `CMakeLists.txt`? I mean something like this: `set(SFML_ROOT "C:/Program Files/SFML-2.4.2")`

Comment: ok, so i made a new projekt (it just has the autogenerated main.cpp/helloworld and CMakeLists.txt), and there is the same problem. when first set up it works, but as soon as i reload the projekt, i get the "No rule to make target" Error. I will add the output of Cmake window.